# Rails: How to sort models by an associated model's field with condition?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have three models:

```
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feedback_units
  has_many :feedbacks, through: :feedback_units
end

class Feedback < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feedback_units
  has_many :units, through: :feedback_units
end

class FeedbackUnit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :feedback
end
```

This is what I want:

Feedback model has a result field. If result is true or false, the feedback is closed. If result is nil, the feedback is unclosed. I want to sort from the unit with the highest number of unclosed feedbacks to the unit with the lowest. It should be at the bottom of the list even if the unit has no feedback.

For example:

| Unit | Number of Closed Feedbacks | Number of Unclosed Feedbacks | Total Number of Feedbacks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unit_A | 14 | 5 | 19 |
| Unit_B | 35 | 23 | 58 |
| Unit_C | 112 | 17 | 129 |
| Unit_D | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Unit_E | 36 | 0 | 36 |
| Unit_F | 0 | 19 | 19 |
| Unit_G | 0 | 0 | 0 |

It should be sorted as follows:

| Unit | Number of Closed Feedbacks | Number of Unclosed Feedbacks | Total Number of Feedbacks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unit_B | 35 | **23 <-** | 58 |
| Unit_F | 0 | **19 <-** | 19 |
| Unit_C | 112 | **17 <-** | 129 |
| Unit_A | 14 | **5 <-** | 19 |
| Unit_D | 0 | **0 <-** | 0 |
| Unit_E | 36 | **0 <-** | 36 |
| Unit_G | 0 | **0 <-** | 0 |

It doesn't matter how the units without unclosed feedbacks are sorted. The last three units can be sorted as follows:

| Unit | Number of Closed Feedbacks | Number of Unclosed Feedbacks | Total Number of Feedbacks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| . | . | . | . |
| Unit_E | 36 | 0 | 36 |
| Unit_D | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Unit_G | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I tried to do it this way but it didn't:

```
Unit.distinct
    .left_joins(:feedbacks)
    .group('feedbacks.result IS NULL')
    .order('feedbacks.result IS NULL ASC, COUNT(feedbacks.result IS NULL)')
```

This should be in the single query and return ActiveRelation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unit.left_joins(:feedbacks).group("units.id").select(
    'units.id,
     sum(case when feedbacks.result is null and feedbacks.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS unclosed, 
     sum(case when feedbacks.result is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS closed, 
     sum(case when feedbacks.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total').order('unclosed DESC')
```

This will work for both PostgreSQL and MySql